# Limit arctan(ln n)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I think it's obvious that the limit is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but I can't figure out how to solve it in a rigorous way, without the use of undetermined expressions involving infinities.
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\arctan(\ln n))$$
Observation: this is the limit of a sequence, therefore $n$ is always an positive integer.

Comment: Prove that $\arctan\ln n\le\pi/2$ for all $n$, and that for any $y<\pi/2$, you can pick $N$ such that $\arctan\ln n>y$ for all $n\ge N$.

Comment: @Otávio I guess [this](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=469697) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \ln x = \infty$

Step 2: Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \arctan x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: So, I want to solve without using the concept of limits going to infinity.

Comment: @OtávioRapôso **without**?

Comment: @OtávioRapôso, I don't think this is possible, since the question was about a limit to infinity.

Comment: @ClementC. That is true, since $\log n$ is not an integer for any $n$.

Comment: I want a proof more like the one suggested by @RahulNarain.

Comment: That's going to implicitly use the fact that $\lim_{\infty}\ln=\infty$ (through the composition of limits); the only difference is that instead of using the theorem of composition, it'll do it "manually" via quantifiers.